# Two metadata hashes at the end of the bytecoe

Tags: solidity, bytecode, solidity-0.6.x, meta-data

doing my own research i saw that the metadata hash is added to the end of the bytecode and i can extract and decode it with cbor. I know that we can identify them by different ways, in this case with `0xa264` and the others code (as ipfs hash, etc).

The thing that i can't understand is why my bytecode has two times this hashes but with different ipfs hash? I mean -  has the same structure but the only thing that i see different is the part where should be the 34 bytes ipfs hash. Even the CBOR gave me two output.

The contract have the following properties that maybe can be the reason but i didn't saw any about that. The contract work with a "**pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2**", with **0.6.12** compiler version and with **3 libraries that we have to link**. The contract work good.

I compile the contract different times and with different libraries addresses. I'll add the part of the end of the bytecode from two differents output of the compiler (with different libraries addresses)

**1st.** `a2646970667358221220526f62c07db9ff568122eb19597ea8d6e89329d6b41d7ec47da66acdef3bd84564736f6c634300060c0033a26469706673582212205b8f460754c7294741a9e497c22395c4fcb9fd262b7f1c3b75f5a7c3d8dc3faf64736f6c634300060c0033`

**2nd**
`a2646970667358221220710f375729f8644f33c8b9034affc2f78bb4230b8f1acbe35f815e82eaf042ca64736f6c634300060c0033a26469706673582212203efa159d534be4d0a84e0ee78b318319684ed223b1e8d8c0c7ed6563ab01e81b64736f6c634300060c0033`

Both bytecodes come from the same contract, the only thing different is that were compiled with different libraries addresses.
As you see, both have the `0xa264`, but is repeated two times. Have the same compiler version here `64736f6c634300060c` that correspond to: `64736f6c6343` = `0x64 's' 'o' 'l' 'c' 0x43` and the compiler version `0.6.12` = `0060c`; which is repeadted two times. But the only different is the hashes ipfs between the "copies" in the same bytecode.

I hope I have made myself sufficiently clear, why it seems to repeat itself twice is beyond me and I can't find any reference to it.
I want to know how to make the same metadata hash that is added to the end with CBOR and the metadata as string obtained by the compiler. :)